# php number_format is not giving expected output after odbc_connect

Tags: php, number-formatting

Please check the output of the code bellow.

```
<?php
define("DSN","somedb");
define("USER","");
define("PASS","");

echo number_format(17, 2, '.', ',');
echo number_format(19, 2, '.', ',');

$dbObj = odbc_connect(DSN,USER,PASS);

echo number_format(17, 2, '.', ',');
echo number_format(19, 2, '.', ',');
?>
```

now after odbc_connect for the code bellow:

echo number_format(17, 2, '.', ',');

### expected output is

17.00

### but it's giving output

16.:0

and same thing happening for 19 too. for all the other numbers output is as expected.

i am using windows server 2008 , apache 2.2, php 5.2.17

i have found this

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47418&edit=1

but this doesn't give a solution

can anyone tell me what is the problem. i am sure some of you have faced this problem. so please let me know what this is and how to solve/overcome it.

Comment: Someone in that thread suggested it could be due to VC6 build of PHP. Perhaps this wouldn't happen in VC9? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

Just Try this..

$num = number_format(17, 2, '.', '');

Comment: thanx for the response. but getting same result.